# My Nativescript http fetch isn't resolving properly

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am trying to login a user.

I am calling the following API to check the credentials:

> http://5c55225d84df580014cd06a3.mockapi.io/users?search=Ally45

Even though my call to my API appears to be returning correct data, my code isn't recognizing the returned data for some reason.

In my login-page.xml , I am calling the login() function when the user taps the login button:

**login-view-model.js**

```
// some code omitted for brevity...

function LoginViewModel() {
const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    processing: false,
    email: "Ally45",
    password: "12345",

    login() {
        this.processing = true;
        userService.login({
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        }).then(() => {
            this.processing = false;

            topmost().navigate("./home/home-page");

        })
        .catch((e) => {
            this.processing = false;
            alert("Unfortunately we could not find your account.");
        });
    },
   });

    return viewModel;
   }
```

so I simply want to log the user in , then go to home page.

Here is my userService.login function that is being called above:

**user-service.js**

```
exports.login = function (user) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    httpModule.getJSON("http://5c55225d84df580014cd06a3.mockapi.io/users?search=" + user.email)
    .then( resolve(response))

    .catch((error) => { handleErrors(error); reject(); })
    })  

};
```

( For testing, I am only checking to see if the email exists "Ally45" in this example , as the JSON is returning )

**Results Being Returned**

I should be being re-directed to the home screen but I never get there.

Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks. So stuck...

John

Comment: It seems to be work just fine on my end, let's know if you can update this [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=9pw7vJ) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: That is interesting. Your playground sample appears to function properly. That means, something else is causing the fetch to fail. I am going to post the entire page's code in the playground and put the link here, the minute I get home from work.

Comment: @Manoj ( and others ) -- Here is my exact code, in the Playground:  [My Code In Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=sDRUeP&v=4)

As you will see, my code never successfully logs in, like it should.

Comment: You had a typo issue `const userService = require("~/services/user-service");` supposed to be `const userService = require("~/services/user-services");`, otherwise I see JSON data in the logs.

Comment: I fixed that typo, and changed user-services. Here is the updated code, which still isn't bringing you to the home screen when you enter Ally45 ( which should get you by ):

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=sDRUeP&v=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Http fetch doesn't have any issues, it's only the way you are processing the response. When you hit that URL you get the below object on your `result`

```
[
 {
  "id": "43",
  "createdAt": "2019-02-01T05:54:43.766Z",
  "username": "Ally45"
 }
]
```

Which is an array but you are testing it as `result.id === undefined`, obviously it's `undefined` and you are calling `reject()`

Your condition suppose to be `result.length === 0 || result[0].id === void 0`

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=sDRUeP&v=9)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was following a tutorial example which was returning an object apparentyl , and this is where I was getting confused.